# Does a question about vehicle catalytic converters environmental effect fit?

Tags: discussion

Catalytic converters in cars are catalyzing some nitrous oxide, carbon monoxide and hydrocarbons at the expense of engine efficiency and thus increasing net carbon dioxide emission. With today's focus on minimizing carbon dioxide emission the catalytic converters seems to burden the environment. Does a question about catalytic converters suitability for the environment fit in Stack Exchange Biology?

Comment: I doubt; Can you formulate your Q here? To me it sounds either Earth Science.SE or perhaps Chemistry.SE, maybe Physics.SE

Comment: In addition to the comment from @AliceD, I have the suspicion that you are trying to provoke a discussion about something that does not have a factual answer. That would almost certainly be off-topic here imho.

Comment: I agree with @aliceD; if there isn’t a specific link between catalytic converters and biology (which there isn’t in the example above) it would be off-topic. Earth science or physics definitely sounds like better places to ask.